# what's meaning of the percentage for color stop in css3 radial gradient

Tags: html, css, gradient, radial-gradients

This maybe a simple question, but I didn't find a clear explanation for this.

I know in css3, the syntax for setting up a `radial gradient` is as following:

```
radial-gradient(shape size at position, start-color, ..., last-color);
```

If I set sth like this:

```
radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%, #f00 50%, transparent 50%);
```

I thought the red circle will be positioned in the center, and the radius of the red circle would be **50%*containerWidth**(or containerHeight).  i.e. the circle will just touch the edge of the outer container, but what I got is not, please see the demo:

[DEMO ON JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hrhktkbzyy/af9cxgwb/)

So can anybody help to explain what's the exact meaning of the 50% here please(`#f00 50%`)?  Many thanks.

---

based on @'s answer:

> the 50% is refered to the diagonal from the center to the square
>   corner

I also put several demo here:

[MORE DEMO ON JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hrhktkbzyy/af9cxgwb/4/)

Because under the default option, the percentage is between the gradient stop radius and the diagonal, so when the ratio is `2**0.5/2≈0.707`, the circle will touch the edges of the square.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 50% in the color stop depends on the size of the image that is being generated.

And the size of the image depends on your choice between the 4 posible values for this property.

If you do not set it, the farthest-corner option is choosen (so, in your example, the 50% is refered to the diagonal from the center to the square corner

```css
div{
  width:100px;
  height:160px;
  border:solid 1px blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

.gradient1{
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side at 50% 40%, #f00 50%, transparent 50%);
}
.gradient2{
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-corner at 50% 40%, #f00 50%, transparent 50%);
}
.gradient3{
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle farthest-side at 50% 40%, #f00 50%, transparent 50%);
}
.gradient4{
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at 50% 40%, #f00 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient1"></div>
<div class="gradient2"></div>
<div class="gradient3"></div>
<div class="gradient4"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @vals, thank you.  Your anwer 'the 50% is refered to the diagonal from the center to the square corner' is exactly what I want to know.

Answer (score 1):

`center 50% 50%` places the gradient center at the center of the container, `#f00 50%` colors the gradient with red color **up to 50% of radius** the rest `50%` being transparent, exactly what you see in jsfiddle. In other words the percent refers to the size (i.e radius) of the gradient object (which in the case of a radial gradient it is the radius, as it unfolds from the center outwards).

[image]

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient