# SVG being hidden by gradient overlay in IE only, works fine in Chrome

Tags: css, radial-gradients

I'm trying to display an SVG using `.pin {background: (rest of code)}`. It's supposed to look like a 3D push pin pushed into paper. To achieve that, I'm using an alpha transparency radial gradient over an SVG so I can easily control quality of size and add depth. My code looks great on Chrome. In IE (version 11), however, the SVG doesn't show. I think my gradient cover is hiding the SVG in IE. It shows up transparently proper in Chrome. What can I do to fix this?

You have to load my question on IE to even see a problem, as like I said, it looks fine in Chrome. I tested this question in both and only IE showed my problem. I put the original code where the SVG gets hidden, then put the code again with a second pin div but took out the gradient code, which causes the SVG to be visible again, but without my nifty gradient.

```css
.pin1 {
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(top center, ellipse cover, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%), url('http://www.cafenocturne.com/images/svg/CafeLogoCircleSVG.svg');
  background: radial-gradient(top center, ellipse cover, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%), url('http://www.cafenocturne.com/images/svg/CafeLogoCircleSVG.svg');
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  background-position: -2px -2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .55);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .55);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .55);
  -webkit-radial-gradient: top center, ellipse cover, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%;
  radial-gradient: top center, ellipse cover, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -20px auto;
}
.pin2 {
  background: url('http://www.cafenocturne.com/images/svg/CafeLogoCircleSVG.svg');
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  background-position: -2px -2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .55);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .55);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .55);
  -webkit-radial-gradient: top center, ellipse cover, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%;
  radial-gradient: top center, ellipse cover, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -20px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="pin1"></div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="pin2"></div>
```

Comment: radial-gradient is not a property. You should use background-image: radial-gradient.

Comment: What syntax? `background-image: radial-gradient(top center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);` ? That didn't help the SVG show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `radial-gradient` is not hiding the SVG background but rather it is making the UA ignore the background property setting on the whole. The reason this is happening is because the radial gradient syntax is wrong. This problem would be seen in all non WebKit browsers. The reason why Chrome is able to display it correctly is because the `-webkit-radial-gradient` has a proper syntax.

The above statement can be verified by inspecting the element in IE. The `background` property would have a zigzag red colored underline (like in MS Word when there is a spelling mistake). This indicates that the property value is incorrect.

Once the [`radial-gradient`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-3/#radial-gradients) syntax is corrected to be inline with the W3C Spec, it works as expected in all browsers. Tested in IE10+ (including Edge), Firefox, Chrome and Opera.

```css
.pin1 {
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at top center, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%), url('http://www.cafenocturne.com/images/svg/CafeLogoCircleSVG.svg');
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  background-position: -2px -2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .55);
  margin: 0 auto -20px auto;
}
.pin2 {
  background: url('http://www.cafenocturne.com/images/svg/CafeLogoCircleSVG.svg');
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  background-position: -2px -2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .55);
  margin: 0 auto -20px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="pin1"></div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="pin2"></div>
```

<sup>I have trimmed down the code by removing some browser specific properties for brevity.</sup>

**Notes:**

- There is no direct equivalent for `cover` inside the `radial-gradient` syntax. You can use one of the available size options instead of it. The default value is `farthest-corner`. You can find more information about the various size options in [vals' answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34253209/whats-meaning-of-the-percentage-for-color-stop-in-css3-radial-gradient/34255350#34255350).
- The syntax and values described in [this WebKit blog article](https://webkit.org/blog/1424/css3-gradients/) for radial gradients don't seem to tally with the standards. It lists `cover` and `contain` as options but the below is what [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient) has to say about these values.

  > Early drafts included other keywords (cover and contain) as synonyms of the standard farthest-corner and closest-side respectively.
- As pointed out by vals in his comment to the question, `radial-gradient` is not a property. It is a value and should be used along with the `background-image` property.

Comment: Thank you SO so so so much, you and vals both! I use so much vendor prefixing because I'm not sure what things have become cross-browser standard and which still need the prefixing. Is there a good place to keep track of this sort of thing, like a site that lists what previously-prefixed properties are now standard cross-browser? You significantly cleaned up my code, too! Thanks for making it tighter, neater, and smaller!

Comment: @Hideto: I don't know of any site which provides full details but you can have a look at http://caniuse.com. They provide browser compatibility chart for all properties and mention which need prefixing. I would personally recommend you to have a look at prefix free library (the one I've used in the answer) as it nullifies the need for manually adding prefixes. It adds all required prefixes by itself.